# Local template variable in Angular2 vs.Jade id shortcut

Tags: pug, angular

Angular2 introduces the local template variable, generated with `#var`.

Jade Template Engine converts this to `#var="var"`.

Is there any way to prevent this, otherwise it is not possible to access the local template variable since it gets overwritten by `"var"`.

Comment: Try to add `doctype html` to the top of your template.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it works in your case but `\#var` should escape the `#`.
`#{"#"}` might work as well.

See also "Scala Interpolation: #{}" in https://scalate.github.io/scalate/documentation/jade-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do so: `element('#varname'="")`